# c# (episerver) return url

Tags: c#, episerver

I have some pages which require authorization so when a user tries to access them I check the authorize attribute like below

```
public class RystadAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if (!isAuthorized)
            return false;

        return this.Roles.Split(',').Any(httpContext.User.IsInRole); // if the user is logged in but doesn't have particular role required to access the content
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/clients/login");
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have the return url as well so once the user is logged in I will redirect him to page he wanted to go rather than finding that page again. How do I do that? Any pointers?

Comment: Why not use the built-in access rights management? http://webhelp.episerver.com/17-5/cms-admin/access-rights.htm

Comment: because I am using custom login on the front end and not for the admin panel

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this a while ago, the implementation looked similar to this

```
// get the request's current page
var currentPage = filterContext.RequestContext.GetRoutedData<PageData>();

// resolve the url
var virtualPath = UrlResolver.Current.GetVirtualPath(currentPage .ContentLink).VirtualPath;    

// Redirect to custom login page
// possibly urlEncode virtualPath
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(string.Concat("~/clients/login?redirectUrl=", virtualPath));

// or
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(string.Concat("~/clients/login?redirectUrl=", virtualPath));
```

Handle the `redirectUrl` on your login page